# How to clear(empty) a string array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, javabeans

I am getting some details and stored in to a string array(Using getter and setter).After that i am setting it as a bean(huge amount of data is taken).To avoid heap space error  i have to clear the string array everytime after setting it as a bean.Is there any methods to clear it?I am new to this enviornmentAny help will be highly appreciable....

The code is given below.....

```
               while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null &&nextLine.length!=0) {
                   Encapsulation encap=new Encapsulation();



//         System.out.println("product name"+nextLine[1]);
                encap.setId(nextLine[0]);
                encap.setProduct_name(nextLine[1]);
                encap.setProduct_url(nextLine[6]);
                encap.setProduct_image(nextLine[3]);
                encap.setProduct_price(nextLine[5]);
                encap.setProduct_src("www.flowersuk.com");
                encap.setCountry("Uk");
                encap.setDate(myDate);
                encap.setCategory(nextLine[8]);

                cvobj.DBConnection(encap);
               //at here i need to clear the string array.
              }
```

Comment: you can not clear the String object. only you can make reference as null so whenever garbage collector will be called it will get all the garbage

Comment: `nextLine` is a `String` not an array... does this code even compile?

Comment: while after every setting of a bean,String array contains lots of data.So for taking data space is needed inside string .

Comment: Elliott Yes it is compailing and working.after some times it is raising a heap space error

Comment: @Jack I find that hard to believe given `nextLine = reader.readNext()`

Comment: it is declared as  String [] nextLine; earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just `nextLine = null;`? Assuming there are no other references to it left dangling, it should then be eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot believe that a data structure holding **nine** Strings is causing a heap overflow.  Especially since `encap` is redeclared within the loop, hence earlier versions of encap are free to be garbage collected during each loop.

The fault surely lies elsewhere: perhaps in `cvobj.DBConnection(encap);` or in your reader code.

As for your actual question, you don't need to do anything.

p.s. on rereading this answer my tone seems a bit harsh, but not sure how to rewrite it. :-)